# How can I use setters from an interface class?

Tags: java, object, interface

I am quite confused on using methods from an interface class. Basically what I want to do use a set method from an interface class and then use it in another class. When I use this.name = name I get an error. Anyone help?

```
public interface Employee {
   String name = "";
   int employeeID = 0;

public void setName(String name);
public void setEmployeeID(int employeeID);
public String getName();
public int getEmployeeID();

}

public class HourlyEmployee implements Employee {
private int payRate;
private int hoursWorked;

public int getPayRate() {
    return payRate;
}

public void setPayRate(int payRate) {
    this.payRate = payRate;
}

public int getHoursWorked() {
    return hoursWorked;
}

public void setHoursWorked(int hoursWorked) {
    this.hoursWorked = hoursWorked;
}

public String getName() {
        return name;
}

public int getEmployeeID() {
    return employeeID;
}

public void setName(String name) {

}

public void setEmployeeID(int employeeNum) {

}
}
```

Comment: Read about what it means to declare variables in interfaces.

Comment: What you need it to extend Employee class not implement employee interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either move

```
   String name = "";
   int employeeID = 0;
```

to `HourlyEmployee` or change the interface to `abstract class` and extend it. you cant have variables in interface

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces cannot have state. Basically the point of an interfaces is to have no implementation.

To quote the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3):

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.

So your `name` and `employeeID` fields are static and final. That's why you can return them but not reassign them. (And if you could reassign them it would be in error since they are static.)

You will have to make a regular class at some point to have state. For example:

```
public interface Employee {
    public String getName();
    public void setName(String name);
    public long getEmployeeID();
    public void setEmployeeID(long employeeID);

    public double getAnnualEarnings();
    public void setAnnualEarnings();
}

public abstract class AbstractEmployee
implements Employee {
    protected String name;
    protected long employeeID;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public long getEmployeeID() {
        return employeeID;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEmployeeID(long employeeID) {
        this.employeeID = employeeID;
    }
}
```

Subclasses extend `AbstractEmployee` to inherit its state but provide their unique implementation for how their annual earnings are calculated.